# positioning elements (different sizes) next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of divs with different size and width. I would like to automatically place them inside another div and position them like:

[image: rectangles next to each other]

Anyone know what css properties should I use? I tried with floating + display (several combinations) and nothing works for me correctly - I had divs in one line -> a lot of space (because one big element) -> next line -> and so on... and so on...

Comment: use masonary js

Comment: It's a hard task. I am not sure it's even possible to do with just CSS. You could use JS to manipulate positioning, but that's outside of the scope of this thread. Try providing more rules to what it is you are after (minimum spacing between elements / other restrictions / dependencies, ect ...)

Comment: Yeah. I would like to achieve something like Masonry js provides. There is no way to achieve that via css?

Do I need to provide to my element informations about size (height/width)? My elements are auto-generated and I cant determine their sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) you will find it hard to acheive this layout.

[Flexbox layout example](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/media-object/)

You could use a JS plugin such as [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html) which will enable you to acheive the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is place them in a container that has a set size (and probably expanding height according to its content) and then line them up the way you show. The easiest way I can think of is using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It has a `container` class and then you can align your elements within divs and it will also make it automatically responsive.

Tip: Avoid using `position: absolute` and `height:` wherever you can because it messes with the flow of your site.

don't forget to clear your floating elements when needed.